# Windows Safe Mode in Grub Menu

Tags: grub2, windows-xp

Is it possible to place Windows Safe Mode into the Grub menu? If so, what is the script for it? (I am currently running Windows XP and Ubuntu 11.10. I also have the Grub Customizer installed.)

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this exactly in GRUB, but boot options described at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239780 are relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows XP uses a different boot loader than grub. This is why grub must 'chainload' the Windows XP bootloader when you select it. Because of this the options for that bootloader are inaccessable to grub. If you want to get creative however, you could try to find a way to modify/replace the boot.ini from the grub environment so that when you do select Windows, it will look at the modified options in boot.ini and go into safemode instead.